# TextField styling in material-ui@next

Tags: material-ui

I what to change **color of label** and text in **TextField** component.

I am using **material-ui@next.**

and docs from 0.15 does not work ( I have checked it) .

Can someone give me short example how to **override floating label**? ( not changing general theme ! )

thanks

Answer (score 6):

From the [documentation](https://material-ui-next.com/api/text-field/), when you have a `TextField` it is, in fact, an abstraction component of several smaller components

> **Advanced Configuration**
>
> It's important to understand that the text field is a simple
>   abstraction on top of the following components:
>
> FormControl 
>   - InputLabel
>
> - List item
> - Input
> - FormHelperText
> - Blockquote
>
> If you wish to alter the properties applied to the native input, you can do as follow:...

In your `TextField` you can pass props for the Input and Label as follow:

```
<TextField
  defaultValue="react-bootstrap"
  label="Bootstrap"
  InputProps={{
    disableUnderline: true,
    classes: {
      root: classes.textFieldRoot,
      input: classes.textFieldInput,
    },
  }}
  InputLabelProps={{
    shrink: true,
    className: classes.textFieldFormLabel,
  }}
/>
```

this is taken from the last example given in [this page.](https://material-ui-next.com/demos/text-fields/)